# Headless-browser benchmarking tool with latency and bandwidth limit?

Tags: performance, phantomjs, benchmarking, headless

Is there a benchmarking tool similar to `wrk` with the full browser (headless-browser) so that JS & CSS loading time would be measured too?

Also would be nice if it would be able to simulate poor network connection - high latency and low bandwidth.

P.S. I searched all the GitHub and found nothing, can't believe there's no such tool. The only similar tool I found is fantomas, but it more like metrics collector, it's not a load generating tool.

Comment: On what platform? Siege maybe?

Comment: mac, nix. Does Siege support headless-browser?

Comment: Ok, I think yes from what I remember. I remember the error I got from siege, something like can't spawn anymore browser no memory left. Something like that.